# Mockito verify method doesn't get invoked

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am a beginner to Mockito and trying to test the following class.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyService.class);

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 

public void logData(String personData) throws IOException{

    Person person = objectMapper.readValue(personData, Person.class);

    // log info
    logger.info("log person:  {}, {}", person.getName(), person.getAge());

 }
}
```

Following is my test class and I am trying to test whether the readValue method of ObjectMapper gets called.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceTest.class);

ObjectMapper objectMapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);

MyService myService = new MyService();

@Test
public void verifyCallToReadValue() throws IOException{

    String personData = "{\"Name\":\"debieA\",\"Age\":\"31\"}";

    myService.logData(personData);

    verify(objectMapper, times(1)).readValue(personData, Person.class);
   }
 }
```

Error I am getting is "wanted but not invoked Wanted but not invoked:
objectMapper.readValue(......);"

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Mocked objects does not call real methods, use spy instead. Also you have to inject that one into your service.

Comment: Note that you can also set up a mocked object to call the real method with a `when(mymock.foo()).thenCallRealMethod()`.

Comment: try `verify(objectMapper, times(1)).readValue(eq(personData), any(Person.class));`

Comment: @dehasi it gives me a type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

The `ObjectMapper` mock has to be injected as a dependency to `MyService`.

Never create the dependencies of your classes inside the class itself, with `new`, like you do in MyService (`ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()`)!

Note my comments and changes in your code:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyService.class);

//ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); //never do that
//instead init the field in the constructor using an external dependency
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
public MyService(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
}

public void logData(String personData) throws IOException{

    Person person = objectMapper.readValue(personData, Person.class);

    // log info
    logger.info("log person:  {}, {}", person.getName(), person.getAge());

 }
}
```

And then in the test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceTest.class);

ObjectMapper objectMapper = mock(ObjectMapper.class);

@Test
public void verifyCallToReadValue() throws IOException{
    MyService myService = new MyService(objectMapper);
    // here you have to mock the readValue method. Something like this:
    //when(objectMapper.readValue(...)).thenReturn(new Person());
    String personData = "{\"Name\":\"debieA\",\"Age\":\"31\"}";

    myService.logData(personData);

    verify(objectMapper, times(1)).readValue(personData, Person.class);
   }
 }
```

Comment: I tried this and it fails at log info in the service class and person evaluates to null.

Comment: You have to mock the method, otherwise, by default Mockito returns null for objects, default values for primitive types and do nothing for void methods. See my comment in the answer. Should be something like this: `when(objectMapper.readValue(...)).thenReturn(new Person());`

Answer (score 0):

Use @Spy annotation, spy is smart to very call

```
@Spy
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

MyService myService = new MyService();

@Test
public void verifyCallToReadValue() throws IOException{

    String personData = "{\"Name\":\"debieA\",\"Age\":\"31\"}";

    myService.logData(personData);

    verify(objectMapper, times(1)).readValue(personData, Person.class);
   }
 }
```